# Leaves on mandarin tree looking dull

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, citrus

Suddenly I have noticed that the leaves on the mandarin tree are looking dull and curling (whole tree). It's a 3 year old tree and it has been producing lot of fruits.

I watered the tree yesterday and noticed this today. Could it be because of over watering? If yes will the tree recover! I am extremely sad :(

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Most of the leaves have dried out and the tree has started shedding leaves. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Its still summer here in NZ and I am flabbergasted on how could this happen by over watering just once!

Comment: Is the tree in a pot without drainage hole? Unless by “overwatering” you mean “filled up and left standing in a few liters of water”, I *don’t* think that is the root cause.

Comment: Thanks, the tree on the ground and not in a pot. we have clay soil here and I noticed this just after the day I watered in a lot. Usually I will leave the hose on for 5 min, but, that day it was for about 20 min.